# Math software for 3d-visualisation

Tags: mathematical-software

What are good and user-friendly math-softwares for 3d-visualization as in

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x7d13SgqUXg (sphere-eversion process).
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rB83DpBJQsE (divergence curl)
3. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r18Gi8lSkfM (Fourier Transform)

Comment: Given (2), this seems like a question for [MESE](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com); but anyway it does not seem to be a question about research-level mathematics, which means it probably doesn't belong on MO.

Comment: I ask this question to explain my research to graduate students

Comment: Right—to *explain* your research, which is in your capacity as a math educator.  That is why I think it belongs on [MESE](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com).

Comment: If MO community can help with questions on highly-mathematical object visulaizations as in (1) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60512/non-algebraic-curve-visualisation, (2) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282100/any-visualization-software-for-the-intrinsic-metric-of-a-convex-polyhedron, (3) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116333/software-reference-request-three-dimensional-staircase-visualizers-for-monomia.
Then I believe they can help with mine too, for in a visualization is many times intended to deliver concepts.

Comment: In principle, good visualization software could also be used to discover new things in the first place. (Probably it would make a good question to ask for real-life cases in which this has happened.)

Comment: True, especially if the visualization software(s) is user-friendly to play and experiment with. Visualizations of-course helps in more detailed observations that can in turn lead to new discoveries.

Answer (score 1):

I use POV ray -- helps for both research and teaching.

Though I don't know if POV ray is a practical tool to model sphere eversion.